# Swapping machine OS with VM OS

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, linux-mint, swap, bare-metal

For several months I've been playing around on VirtualBox with Linux Mint 20.0 installed on it and have tweaked the OS just the way I now want it.
This VB resides inside of main bare metal Windows 7 Pro.
8 gb ram allocated for each OS.

I would like to swap Linux Mint (on VB) with the main bare metal Win7 OS.
And when the Win7 OS is eventually resident on VB then it will be disconnected from the modem, and only used to run old software when needed.

So, Linux Mint 20.0 will become my new go-to OS on the main bare metal desktop computer.

How can this transfer be most easily accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to P to V the Windows 7 machine first and prove that it was successful (so that you no longer need it in physical format).   You will need the machine running until you successfully do the V to P.

You need to do this first so as to allow a physical machine that you can write Linux Mint to.

Virtual Box V to P may be a bit complicated (harder than VMware, say).

Follow this Stack Exchange guide as a starting point.

[V to P Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42585/migrating-a-virtualbox-virtual-machine-into-a-physical-dual-boot-system)

> Install virtualbox on LM13 [ or other OS ]so you can run your old LM12
> install. Then just use rsync to migrate your files and directories
> over. If you haven't installed many services, there probably isn't
> that much you need to do beyond bringing over your home directory.